# The B-space of all linear and continuous mappings defined from one B-space to another.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces on the same field $R$. We denote by $L(E,F)$ the space of all linear and continuous mappings defined from $E$ to $F$. Check that $L(E,F)$ is a Banach space.

Comment: I think to solve this qustion should be use stainhaus theorem , is it  true ?

Comment: Please any one known the solve tell me because i have exame at sunday

Comment: If $F$ is a Banach space, $L(E,F)$ with the operator norm is a Banach space, too. You can show this straight forward using the definition of Banach spaces by considering a Cauchy sequence $(A_n)$ in $L(E,F)$ and showing that there exists a linear map $A:E\to F$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=A$.

Comment: Thank you, you mean i can use the same prove from E To F but if only F Banach space .

Comment: I try use  a finite diminsional of normed space is Banach if i prove that L(E,F) is finite from Banach steinhaus theorem . Can you help me if this method true

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to show that $L(E,F)$ is finite dimensional, especially since we know nothing about the spaces $E$ and $F$. I gave you a prove using Cauchy sequences below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(Y,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space, then $(L(X,Y),\|\cdot\|)$ with the operator norm $\|\cdot\|$ is a Banach space.
(Note that this especially means that the dual space $X'=L(X,\mathbb R)$ is a Banach space since $\mathbb R$ is a Banach space.)

To show this let $(A_n)\subset L(X,Y)$ be a Cauchy sequence. For all $x\in X$ we have $$\|A_nx-A_mx\|=\|(A_n-A_m)x\|\leq \|A_n-A_m\|\cdot \|x\|$$

and hence $\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists N_0$ with $\|A_nx-A_mx\|<\varepsilon$ $\forall n,m\geq N_0$.

This means $(A_nx)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$ and since $Y$ is a Banach space $Ax:=\lim_{n\to\infty} A_nx$ exists. This gives us a mapping $A:X\to Y$. It is not difficult to prove that $A$ is linear.

For all $x\in X$ the following estimate holds

$$\|Ax\|\leq\lim_{n\to\infty} \|A_n\|\|x\|\leq \limsup \|A_n\|\|x\|$$
which gives us the continuouity of $A$.

For $n\to \infty$ and all $x\in X$ with $\|x\|_X\leq 1$ we have

$$\|Ax-A_mx\|<\varepsilon\quad \forall m>N_0$$ and hence $$\sup_{\|x\|_X\leq 1} \|(A-A_m)x\|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow \|A-A_m\|<\varepsilon$$

But this proves that $\|A-A_m\|\to 0$ for $m\to\infty$ and hence our Cauchy sequence converges, which means $L(X,Y)$ is a Banach space.